# Google Artifact Registry access from different projects

Tags: google-cloud-platform, repository, google-kubernetes-engine, cicd, google-artifact-registry

I would like to configure Google Artifact Registry in a single GKE project in a way that all other projects could access this Centralized Artifact Registry.

In Google documentation is not clear to me how to achieve this, specially for Google Kubernetes Engine nodes using default account.

Would you know how to configure the access to achieve that scenario?

Thank you,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With GKE the node service account pull the image to run it on the node. Therefore, you have to grant that node service account (or the compute engine default service account if you use it) the permission to read the images in your Artifact Registry.

You have 2 level to grant the `roles/artifactregistry.reader` role on your service account

- Directly in the IAM page of your Artifact registry project. Like that, the service account will have access to ALL the registry that you have created in the project
- On at the registry level to grant the service account for that registry only, and disallow the others.

Here an example:

- Select your registry (checkbox on the left)
- Add principal in the permission section on the right

[image]

Comment: For the cases where the artifact registry is located in 1 project, but the hosts of GKE are located in another project, would that also work? From my project with Artifact Registry, I was not able to find the principal for any other project to add it.

Comment: you have to add the account used by your GKE project. It's an email, add the service account as you add a user account email. Same principle, you grant an identity!

Comment: Do you know if there are any egress costs associated with this kind of usage? Thanks

Comment: If you are in the same region (the artifact registry and the GKE nodes) you should not have egress cost.

Answer (score 1):

If you are adding principal to that registry be infomred that you can't add service account doesn't exisit yet; the service account in the projecy where your GKE cluster runs must exisit first as GCP won't allow adding non-existing service accounts.

This may create a chicken-egg issue for you if you really want to manage everything in that project with automated workflow where the artifact registry exisit. so you may need to have an intermediate stage after you proision your registry in a project and GKE and all its service accounts in separate project, you would need something like stitcher to connect both together, this is a bit hectic if you would do that in IAC

However you should be thinking of an alternative way to do so to avoid any